# Парсинг и фильтрация CSV файлов

Tags: python, numpy, csv, фильтрация, анализ-данных

Пример содержимого CSV файла:

```
название;цена;доставка
Аренда топ игрового компьютера на RTX 2060/2070;398;нет доставки
Ноутбук Aorus RTX 2070 240Hz;150000;нет доставки
Игровой пк 2700x, RTX 2070 Super, 32 Gb DDR4;95000;нет доставки
Игровой пк rtx 2070 i5 9400f монитор/мышь/клава;70000;нет доставки
HP omen 15 dh0026ur 4k RTX 2070 новый;140000;есть доставка
Игровой пк - RTX2070 Super 8Gb, i5 9400F, 16Gb;86000;есть доставка
Игровой процессор на RTX2070 и i5-9600;90000;есть доставка
Asus Strix RTX 2070 8Gb;31000;нет доставки
Gigabyte Geforce RTX 2070 Windforce (8гб);32500;нет доставки
RTX 2070 Super Asus Rog Strix OC Обмен;39990;есть доставка
Игровой компьютер AMD Ryzen 5/24GB/RTX2070/1TB SSD;85000;нет доставки
```

Задача, вывести строки, которые попадают в интервал цены - от и до (второй столбец файла), и записать их в другой файл.

Решение задачи предложенное [@MaxU](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1127591/217579):

```py
import pandas as pd 

price_ot = 5000
price_do = 300000
delivery = 'есть доставка'
brand = 'Aorus'

(pd
 .read_csv('data.csv', sep=';')
 .query('@price_ot <= `цена` <= @price_do and @delivery in `доставка` and @brand in `название`')
 .to_csv('new_data.csv', sep=';', index=False))
```

Есть ли способ, который позволяет сделать фильтр не по полному вхождению, как сейчас для `delivery`, а по отдельному слову в ячейке, например нужно оставить строки в которых содержится только вхождение одного слова 'Aorus' в первом столбце?

Comment: а в чем проблема прочитать и посмотреть? а потом сохранить в новый файл,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Есть ли способ, который позволяет сделать фильтр не по полному
>   вхождению, как сейчас для delivery, а по отдельному слову в ячейке,
>   например нужно оставить строки в которых содержится только вхождение
>   одного слова 'Aorus' в первом столбце?

Воспользуйтесь методом [Series.str.contains("reg_ex")](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=";")
res = df.loc[df["название"].str.contains("Aorus")]
```

---

результат:

```
In [8]: res
Out[8]:
                       название    цена      доставка
5  Ноутбук Aorus RTX 2070 240Hz  150000  нет доставки
```

---

данный метод можно комбинировать с фильтрацией из [другого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1127591/211923):

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=";")
res = df.query(qry).loc[lambda x: x["название"].str.contains(r"i[79]")]
```

---

результат:

```
In [9]: res
Out[9]:
                               название   цена       доставка
2  Intel Core i7 + Nvidia RTX 2070/2060  33900  есть доставка
```

Comment: В регулярном выражении можно прописать "регистрозависимость" символов? В смысле чтобы перебор вёлся без учета регистра.

Comment: `.str.contains(..., case=False)`

Answer (score 5):

Воспользуйтесь модулем [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html):

```
import pandas as pd  #  pip install pandas

price_from = 30000
price_to = 35000
delivery = ["есть доставка"]
qry = "@price_from <= `цена` <= @price_to and `доставка` in @delivery"

(pd
 .read_csv(filename, sep=";")
 .query(qry)
 .to_csv(new_filename, sep=";", index=False))
```

Comment: не могу понять как добавить доп. условие:

price_from = 10000
price_to = 30000
deliv_da = 'есть доставка'
deliv_net = 'нет доставки'

(pd
 .read_csv('data.csv', sep=";")
 .query("@price_from <= `цена` <= @price_to")
 .query("deliv_da = `доставка`")
 .to_csv('new_data.csv', sep=";", index=False))

задача оставить строки в которых третий столбец равен "есть доставка"

Comment: @Jimmy, дополнил ответ

Comment: спасибо, всё работает

Comment: есть ли какое-то регулярное выражение которое позволяет сделать фильтр не по полному вхождению как сейчас для delivery, а по отдельному слову в ячейке, например нужно оставить строки в которых содержится слово 'Ryzen' в первом столбце.

Comment: @Jimmy, попробуйте задать новый SO вопрос ;)

Comment: гугл не знает что такое "SO вопрос" :)

Comment: оу :) понял понял

Comment: @Jimmy Нет, вы непоняли. В гугл не надо было идти, надо было глаза поднять и чуть вправо посмотреть - [Задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).